# Conflicting situation from concurrent use of pdfpages and pgfpages in beamer

Tags: beamer, pdfpages, pgfpages

From my `beamer` slides I produce multi slide per page pdfs which are easier for printing.

Things went fine all these years until I used [pdfpages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/) and [pgfpages](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfpages.sty) in the same file. Here is the stripped down minimal file (from a shell script generated version),

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pdfpages}


\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=2.5mm,landscape]


\begin{document}

\includepdf{mypdf.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Whenever I pdflatex this file, I get an error message in the line of,

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \raise \ht \@tempboxa \hbox {}\AM@fbox 
                                                  {\AM@ARBug@hook \AM@reflec...
l.16 \end{document}
```

I find that if either of `pdgpages` or `pgfpages` is omitted, things go fine.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I get no error; this is my version of `pdfpages`: `pdfpages.sty 2012/08/31 v0.4t`. You can see it in the log file if you add `\listfiles` to the preamble of the `.tex` document.

Comment: My versions are 
pgfpages 2004/11/05 ver 0.01,
pdfpages 2009/02/07 v0.4g,
pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian),
Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Mine too; what version of `pdfpages` do you have?

Comment: pdfpages 2009/02/07 v0.4g, please see my previous comment

Comment: You should try with the newer one. The best is to update your TeX Live.

Comment: What is your version of beamer?

Comment: `beamer.cls 2013/01/04 3.26`

Comment: Updating (manually from CTAN, not using apt-get) pdfpages solved the problem.

Comment: For the record, I get the same error using pdfpages in a beamer document, without knowingly using pgfpages.
pdfpages version is pdfpages 2009/02/07 v0.4g
Installing the newer version from CTAN made the error disappear.
Thanks.